# how to execute multiple command at the same time

Tags: powershell, windows-services

I have script that stop and start windows services. Currently, it is working fine thru foreach loop; however, it is time consuming. I'm looking for a way to trigger all at the same time instead of go thru $computer object foreach loop and execute 1 by 1. Please advise. Great appreciate

```
    Foreach ($v in $computers) 
{
    if ($v.value -eq "true") 
    {
        $computers = $v.Name.Split("_")
        Write-Host "Processing " $computers[1]
        StartOrStopService $computers[1] $StartOrStopService.ToLower()          
    }
}
```

Best Regards,

Comment: take a look at `Invoke-Command`. it can accept a list of systems AND a scriptblock ... and then run the scriptblock on each system _in parallel_. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using jobs to get the execution go through in parallel

```
Foreach ($v in $computers) 
{
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName . -ScriptBlock {
        Param($v, $StartOrStopService)
        if ($v.value -eq "true") 
        {
            $computers = $v.Name.Split("_")
            Write-Host "Processing " $v.Name
            StartOrStopService $v.Name $StartOrStopService.ToLower()          
        }
    } -AsJob -ArgumentList $v, $startorStopService
}
```

You can use Get-Job | Receive-Job if you wanted to see the output of the commands.